# How to Model Firestore Data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore and trying to develop a data model for my app.

**Background:** I have a dating type of app with 3 primary ways that users will communicate with one another. Liking, dismissing, and commenting user profiles. Users likes & comments are private. In other words, only I can see who's liked or commented my profile (it's not like Social media where everyone can see who's liked a post). I'll need to be able to query users to know who's dismissed their profile so I won't show it to those users again. I'll also need to know who's liked/commented a users profile so I can query which users have liked/commented each other (they've matched)

- Users can like many profiles and vice versa
- Users can dismiss/skip many profiles and vice versa
- Users can comment on many profiles and vice versa

I believe this means I'll need a root collection for ***likedUsers, dismissedUsers, and commentedUsers***

**Problem:**
For dismissed users, I thought I'd store every single user as a Document of the dismissedUsers root collection and store every user they've skipped as a field/value pair like so...

***dismissedUsers/User/user1, user2, user3, etc***

The above would create the many-many relationship I want where dismissedUsers can have many users and users can have many dismissedUsers. However, I don't believe it would be scalable as the User Document would grow too large.

**Question:** How do I create this many-many relationship where dismissedUsers can have many users and users can have many dismissedUsers so that it's scalable and least expensive? And query it?

Comment: Adding documents to a subcollection under document D doesn't make the size of document D any larger.  Each document is fully independent of each other, no matter where it gets organized.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok, so I should just add a sub-collection to the User Document for likedUsers, dismissedUsers, commentedUsers? Understood, but I read that when doing that the data is scoped to that particular user (preventing querying across parent documents)? Is that not the case?

Comment: You might want to read about collection group queries for querying across subcollections with different parent documents.

Comment: The problem with this question is it's too vague and we don't have enough info to evaluate the issue. For example *the User Document would grow too large* what does that mean? Too large for what? You could store tens of thousands of documents with that format in a */users/uid* document and it would be a tiny amount of data. Additionally, why even store it there in in the first place? Why not have a separate collection to store users dismissed users? Then it's totally separate from the users doc. *How do I create this many-many relationship* - have users and dismissedUsers collections.

Comment: @Jay Assuming the hierarchy is as follows: users/user1/dismissedUsers/user2,user3,user4,etc.  My question is how do I model and do an inequality-type query to load all users (for user1) except those in the dismissedUsers sub-collection?

Comment: Again, it's hard to answer because it's vague. *to load all users* All users... as in all users in the entire database? Some sub section of users? What is *all users*? To craft a model, all of the major components need to be taken into account and we would need to understand the relationships.  For example, how does a user become dismissed from when they were not dismissed? Why are dismissed users stored within a users node? That makes things like queries and observes much more complex. What if a user account is deleted? Should those also be deleted from the dismissed users?

Comment: @Jay I'd load a sub-section of users (maybe few hundred). A user becomes dismissed when a user taps a "dismiss" button. Users are liked when a user taps a "like" button. The sub-section of users (a few hundred) who haven't been "dismissed" nor "liked" should be loaded for the currentUser. Maybe dismissedUsers should be stored at root? If user is deleted, yes delete from dismissedUsers (makes sense)

Comment: I think you can see the problem with this kind of question on SO. It's very open-ended and a lot more data is needed. For example, you're loading a sub-set of users who are not dismissed. Is that 10 users? 1000 Users? What if you have a million users in the database - how does the user 'go through' the users and decide which one to dismiss or not-dismiss? Once those aspects are pinned down it will be easier to model but as is, it's impossible for us to made any kind of accurate recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would ask myself why I am using Firestore, being a document database, instead of choosing a relational database. I personally love Firestore and highly recommend it. We pick a document database because it is faster and easier to use in many ways. In other ways it is a drawback because you have very limited query power. It sounds to me like your brain is working towards a relational database implementation.

**Here is one solution**

First of all I would try to avoid storing user data in more than one location to avoid anomalies (of course right). I would have one collection of users where I stored all user data with a unique id (best to use the one that Firestore assigns so I don't have collisions). Within each users document I would link a subcollection for dismissed, liked, been dismissed by someone else, liked by someone else etc.. I would keep a record of all users (just the user id) that they have dismissed, liked, been dismissed by, been liked by etc.. This way I can look up all data for who that user has liked or disliked and display whatever I want to that user accordingly.

**Drawbacks**

You will have to write twice per like, dismiss etc. Use a batch write to update both the liked and likee data at the same time.

Comment: Ok that makes sense to create a sub-collection for the User Doc. However, do I still have querying power on parent documents? For instance, has User1 liked User30?

Comment: Yes because you can check User1's "liked" collection to see if the userId for User30 is there. The path would be something like firestore.collection('users').doc(User1's user ID).collection('liked') and then query that collection for User30. A third (unrelated) user could still access this data if you wanted to but by the sounds of your application you  want to keep it private so set security rules accordingly.

Comment: One of the benefits of giving each user their own collections with likes, dismisses etc. is that you can set strict security rules so that savvy users can't see info they shouldnt.

Comment: one more question, assume I have the following hierarchy: users/user1/dismissedUsers/user2,user3,etc - how could I use an inequality query to load all users (for user1) NOT in dislikedUsers sub-collection?

Comment: This is one of the drawbacks of a document db like firestore. I dont know of a way to do that with a firestore query You may want to post another question asking this and see if anyone else has any ideas. Otherwise you may need need a relational database with more query  power.

Comment: @CadenJoe The above question in the comment isn't answerable... Your hierarchy is *users/user1/dismissedUsers/user2,user3* and then you ask for a way to *query to load all users (for user1)* but you've not indicated a structure for where *all users for user1* is located? If we knew that, we could formulate an answer. There *is* a solution but a structure is needed that contains *all users for user1*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a collection of users who liked, dismissed, or commented on another users profile. You can have one user collection which stores all users. Inside each user document you can have three array of the user ids of the users that liked, commented, and/or dismissed a user profile. Just make sure that the document ID of the documents inside the users collection matches the user id of the corresponding user.

Comment: I don't believe creating an array for liked, dismissed, commented users on a User Document is scalable